# Find radius of convergence of power series

Tags: complex-numbers, power-series

Since we know that

given $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }C_nz^n$, if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }|C_n|^{1/n}$ exists then $R^{-1}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }|C_n|^{1/n}$ where $R$ is the radius of convergence.

But for the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }2^nz^{n^2}$, when I find the radius of convergence of it, should I find

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }|C_n|^{1/n^2}$? Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }|C_n|^{1/n^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }|2^n|^{1/n^2}$ which is $1$. So the convergence radius is $1$.

Am I correct? If no, how to find the convergence radius of the power series that is not in the form of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }C_nz^n$, but like $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }C_nz^{n^2}$ or $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }C_nz^{n!}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does it help to think that $2^nz^{n^2}$ is a subsequence of $2^nz^n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ratio Test works too:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{2^{n+1}z^{(n+1)^2}}{2^nz^{n^2}}\right|
&= 2\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|z|^{n^2+2n+1-n^2} \\
&= 2\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|z|^{2n+1} \\
&=
\begin{cases}
\infty & |z|>1 \\
2      & |z|=1 \\
0 & |z|<1
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
By the Ratio Test, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^nz^{n^2}$ converges for $|z|<1$ and diverges for $|z|\geq 1$. In particular, $R=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the $n$th root test,
$$|2^nz^{n^2}|^{1/n}=2|z|^n\ .$$
If $|z|<1$ this tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ so the series converges; if $|z|>1$ this tends to $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ so the series diverges.  Therefore the radius of convergence is $1$.

You could also do it by the ratio test.